# Django error: get() returned more than one userData -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to build a coupon system in Django, and here I'm trying to display the balance that a person has with a vendor by comparing the database, after pressing the submit button. However, I'm facing the above mentioned error.

Here is the html:

```
{% block content %}
   <div class="container">
   <h1>Welcome to your page, @{{ user.username }}</h1>
   <h3>Select vendor to check your balance!</h3>
   <br>
<form method="POST" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check Balance</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
{% if args.model %}
   <h4>You need to pay Rs {{ args.model }} to vendor {{ args.choice }}    
   </h4>

    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'profiles'

urlpatterns = [
    path('adminKaLogin/', views.adminKaPage, name="adminHome"),
    path('userLogin/', views.userKaLog, name="userHome"),
]
```

The forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

vendor_choices = [
    ('1','Vendor 1'),('2',"Vendor 2"), ("3", "Vendor 3"),
]    

class select_vendor_form(forms.Form):
    Vendor_choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=vendor_choices,
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

The views.py

```
def userKaLog(request):
    form = select_vendor_form()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = select_vendor_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            choice = form.cleaned_data['Vendor_choices']
            records = userData.objects.get(vendor_number = choice)
            args = {'form': form, 'choice': choice, 'model':records}
            return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', args)
    return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', {'form': form})
```

The models.py:

```
 from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class userData(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField()
    date_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now())
    vendor_number  = models.IntegerField()
```

If the person selects radio button of vendor 2, the output should be the total money owed to vendor 2 by that user. The user I had logged in with has balance with vendor 2. Maybe this is why 2 is being returned? I am unable to get where I am going wrong.

Comment: Looks like you have **multiple** users with a single `vendor_number`. Please also include the model that has the `itemPrice` field.

Comment: Hi. Sorry had included a previous version of the code, have edited it. So if I include the username in _records = userData.objects.get(vendor_number = choice)_ , it would be sorted?